# Does the size of a child LWC count towards the size of the parent LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a LWC that has become too large and is about at it's size limitation, so are going to break it into multiple pieces that all communicate with each other. As I was researching I found most suggesting to embed the child component into the parent component and communicate information between components that way. Using this method, would my parent component size include the size of the child, or are their bundle (?) sizes separate as it relates to Salesforce's file size governing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component's size is only its own markup. In other words, the child component doesn't add to the parent component's total size. This is also why components should be as small and modular as possible, in order to avoid those limits.